# Relate JS Objects to HTML ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

Is there a way I can create multiple JS Objects, each relating to a separate HTML Element with a unique ID? 
Also is there a way that I can do this without ID's, like using `class[1]`?

I can't seem to find any answers

HTML

```
<div class="exampleClass" id="example1"> </div>
<div class="exampleClass" id="example2"> </div>
<div class="exampleClass" id="example3"> </div>
<div class="exampleClass" id="example4"> </div>
```

JS

```
var Object1 = {
data1: "This goes with the first DIV"
}
var Object2 = {
data1: "This goes with the second DIV"
}
var Object3 = {
data1: "This goes with the third DIV"
}
var Object4 = {
data1: "This goes with the fourth DIV"
}
```

I want to relate each JS Object to its own ID/Element

Comment: Have you tried an array?

Comment: Can you explain this further?

Comment: `const arr = {
data1: "This goes with the first DIV"
}, ...` then with a collection of the elements, the 0th element will correspond to `arr[0]`

Answer (score 4):

You can make an array of objects using `querySelectorAll` and `map` with `...` (spreading) to make an array out of the returned `NodeList`:

```js
const arr = [...document.querySelectorAll("div.exampleClass")].map(d => ({ data1: d }));
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<div class="exampleClass" id="example1"> </div>
<div class="exampleClass" id="example2"> </div>
<div class="exampleClass" id="example3"> </div>
<div class="exampleClass" id="example4"> </div>
```

As mentioned by [@Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671222/relate-js-objects-to-html-ids/55671264?noredirect=1#comment98028738_55671264), [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) can be provided with a mapping function - this makes the code more concise:

```js
const arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.exampleClass"), div => ({ data1: div }));
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<div class="exampleClass" id="example1"> </div>
<div class="exampleClass" id="example2"> </div>
<div class="exampleClass" id="example3"> </div>
<div class="exampleClass" id="example4"> </div>
```

Comment: +1 Could also use `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(...), data1 => ({ data1 }))` for a more concise solution

Comment: @Phil Really? How does that work? Does `Array.from` have a built-in mapping function?

Comment: Yep. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: Thanks! I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @JackBashford You should be more specific about elements. You should select `.exampleClass`. And maybe also mention that the second method is slower https://jsbench.me/62juga1ohs/1

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without id. `map()` takes a callback and its second parameter is the current index of element through which its iterating.

```js
let divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.exampleClass')];

let data = divs.map((x,id) => ({[id]:x}));
console.log(data)
```

```html
<div class="exampleClass"> </div>
<div class="exampleClass"> </div>
<div class="exampleClass"> </div>
<div class="exampleClass"> </div>
```